# PHPmailer remote execution vulnerability check

Tags: email, php

I have a RHEL6 system and I want to verify if the system is vulnerable to `phpmailer` remote code execution exploit. I did not setup the server.

How can I figure if the server is vulnerable?
I tried `rpm -qa | grep php`, `yum list | grep php` and it looks like there is no `phpmailer` installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step I would do is to find all `phpmailer` classes residing in your server and determine their versions, and see if those individual versions are affected by one or more vulnerability(ies).

The class name of phpmailer is `class.phpmailer.php` https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

So you would search on your server for:

```
find / -name class.phpmailer.php
```

If you find some on your server, look inside the file for the version.

For example I just searched an old server of mine and found PHPMailer 5.1 there:

```
.---------------------------------------------------------------------------.
|  Software: PHPMailer - PHP email class                                    |
|   Version: 5.1                                                            |
|   Contact: via sourceforge.net support pages (also www.worxware.com)      |
|      Info: http://phpmailer.sourceforge.net                               |
|   Support: http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/                     |
| ------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
```

Last step would be to verify if there are any known vulnerabilities for that version using a vulnerability database. I like using  http://www.securityfocus.com/vulnerabilities, search for:

- **Vendor**: PHPMailer
- **Title**: PHPMailer
- **Version**: 5.1

In this example, for version PHPMailer 5.1, I found no known vulnerabilities.